# _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame5"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am developing project with multiple frames in a single window, I have multiple buttons *login,register,add_Symptoms,edit_symptoms,delete_symptoms* in frame p2. By pressing some button respective operation should be done on frame p5(expected) but I am not able to use frame p5 for repeatedly use, Consider if we press button *login* then code for login should be displayed on frame p5, after that as we press *add_Symptoms* button previous structure should be deleted and new code for add_Symptoms should be displayed in same frame p5.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1280x730")    
#define frames
p1 = Frame(root, background="#D3D3D3", borderwidth = 6,relief=RAISED)
p1.pack(side=RIGHT,fill="y")
p2 = Frame(root, background="#D3D3D3", borderwidth = 3,relief=RAISED)
p2.pack(side=TOP,fill="x")
p3 = Frame(root, background="#D3D3D3", borderwidth = 2,relief=SUNKEN)
p3.pack(side=TOP,fill="x")
p4 = Frame(root, background="white")
p4.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill="x")
p5 = Frame(root, borderwidth = 2)
p5.pack(side=LEFT,anchor="n")

#Funtions for button commands
def login():
    p5.destroy()     #Getting error here
    label = Label(p5,text="Administrator Page",font=("Comic Sans MS",12,"italic"), fg = "red")
    label.pack(padx=80,pady=10)
def add():
    p5.destroy()   #Getting error here
    label = Label(p5,text="Add Symptomps",font=("Comic Sans MS",12,"italic"), fg = "green")
    label.pack(padx=80,pady=10)

add_symptoms = Button(p1,text="Add Symptoms",command=add, state=DISABLED)
add_symptoms.pack(pady=10,padx=5)
login_admin = Button(p5,text="LOGIN",font=("Comic Sans MS",15,"italic"),fg="blue",command=login, width=15)
login_admin.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=25)
root.mainloop()


    **Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\program files\python37\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in  
    __call__
    return self.func(*args)
    File "project.py", line 67, in login
    label = Label(p5,text="Administrator Page",font=("Comic Sans 
    MS",12,"italic"), fg = "red")
    File "c:\program files\python37\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in 
    __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
    File "c:\program files\python37\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in 
    __init__
   (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
```

_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame5"**

Comment: What error are you getting? Please [edit] your question to include the traceback.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `p5.destroy()` from the login `function` . You destroyed the frame after that then you want to pack your `label = Label(p5,text="Administrator Page",font=("Comic Sans MS",12,"italic"), fg = "red")` inside it  which causing the error.

I think you should look at this widget [toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) which works as slave window to the root window.

```
def login():
   # p5.destroy()     #Getting error here
    label = Label(p5,text="Administrator Page",font=("Comic Sans MS",12,"italic"), fg = "red")
    label.pack(padx=80,pady=10)
```

Comment: but My aim to reuse that frame for other purpose